# How to Create an effect such as the one on flixster.rottentomatoes.com

Tags: html

how can one create the effect of having 2 different "scrollable" places of the site, on the example I gave, one is the list of movies and the other is the description, reviews, etc on the right of the list.

Answer (score 0):

DIV tags are scrollable when you set the height of the DIV and then make it overflow: auto.

So:

```
<div style="width: 30%; height: 300px; overflow: auto; float: left;">
Menu stuff here.
</div>
<div style="width: 70%; height: 300px; overflow: auto; float: left;">
Content stuff here.
</div>
```

This would create something like the picture below (I added some extra menu items and content lines w/line breaks and color for effect).

[image]

Comment: but then, how to get rid of the scrollbars and keep the scroll? since on the example of flixster there are no scrollbars other than the default one

Comment: Well, my response to that is the flixster site is broken in FF 3.6. The left side does not scroll, not matter what I do. So... Be careful, it could be a support nightmare. What you could do is use a JS scroller and make the style of the scrollbar invisible. by incorporating it into the design (for instance, white backgrounds for the handles and grip). I have done JS scrollers, though; be careful. Here thyre be tygers. http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/